# can we pull data from on-premise or azure vm to azure databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, etl, databricks, azure-databricks

can we connect the **azure VM** to **azure databricks** such that vm should throw the data to azure databricks directly...
it can throw data to azure data lake but azure databricks should connect to vm.

is there any way to do it ?
and if not then is there any other alternative for that?

please provide steps too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will need to vnet attach your databricks instance to a network that can see your vm. Full details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/vnet-injection

Comment: thanks for the info but did you ever tried it on your own because I tried each and every way possible as mentioned in the hyperlink but its not working as per my knowledge . If you can provide any document or exact steps it would be great help .

Comment: the docs provide the steps - please provide example code of what you have tried. I have done this many times with no issue.